# Proving polynomial function is continuous for Zariski topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: zariski-topology

I am looking to prove that a polynomial function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is continuous for the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{R} $(both domain and range)

How do I do this?

Comment: Well, have you tried taking an open set and seeing whether its inverse image is open?

Comment: How do you define the Zariski topology on a field? There aren't many points…

Comment: @bernard I'm not sure how you define it I haven't heard of this type of topology before?

Comment: @EricWofsey I kmow that's what I have to do but I sure not sure how I actually write these open sets down?

Comment: It is defined on the set of prime ideals of a ring (the *spectrum* of the ring), and a basis of open sets is is $D(a)=\{\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Spec R}\mid \mathfrak p\not\ni a\}$. As a field has only one prime ideal…